# Is this a valid way to use C++ Template Metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm experimenting with templates and i've run into code that looks like this. Code calling a templated method and explicitly passing a struct as a template parameter. That struct contains all the specific logic on how to use the input type.

I want to know if this is a valid way to use C++ templates or is this a mess and should be done with class inheritance? I couldn't find any examples of templates being used like this so I have a feeling theres a better way

```
// Template parameter that holds all the logic for a specific input type
// Similar structs would exist for double, string, etc. In my code these would be classes not primitives
struct HowToHandleIntType {
  using Type = int;

  struct Add {
    int Run(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
  };

  struct Remove {
    void PreRemove(int a) {
      // Do Something to a
    }
    bool Run(int a) {
      // Do Something to a
    }
  }
};

// Generic methods that call into the template struct for all real logic
template <typename HowToHandle>
int add(typename HowToHandle::Type a, typename HowToHandle::Type b) {
  return HowToHandle::Add::Run(a, b);
}

template <typename HowToHandle>
bool remove(typename HowToHandle::Type a) {
  HowToHandle::Remove::PreRemove(a);
  return HowToHandle::Remove::Run(a);
}

// This is how the methods would be used 
add<HowToHandleIntType>(5, 8);
add<HowToHandleDoubleType>(5.0, 8.0);
remove<HowToHandleStringType>("bob");
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like policy based design. There may well be a better design, though.

Comment: Thanks, policy based design does seem similar. In policy based design it looks like the template parameters are used to modify a class in some way. In my situation I have no class and just a list of operations like add,remove,etc and the user can make use of them as long as they pass in the right `HowToHandle` struct

Answer (score 1):

it's definitely **valid**, and usually not a bad design. but maybe it loses the ability from ***type deduction*** which it should have.

consider a design, ***trait-based***:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct HowToHandleThisType;

template<>
struct HowToHandleThisType<int>{
    typedef int Type;
    struct Add{
        // ...
    };
    struct Remove{
        // ...
    };
};

template<typename T, typename Trait = HowToHandleThisType<T>, typename = typename Trait::Type /* SFINAE */>
typename Trait::Type add(T a, T b){
    return Trait::Add::Run(a, b);
}

int main(){
    auto x = add(1, 2); // T = int
}
```

in this case, you needn't explicitly provide `HowToHandleIntType` as the template argument. even users actually may not know the trait `HowToHandleThisType<int>` exists.

but sometimes we may want to, or have to, assign one of these traits to do that, such as `add<int, HowToHandleThisType<int>>(1, 2)` (always we provide another overload to let `add<HowToHandleThisType<int>>(1, 2)` valid), it's equal to your design.